# ReactJS: How to redirect user based on usertype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have three types of user **'A', 'B', 'C'** in my react project. These values are stored in local storage. When a user login successfully, I wanted to redirect them to their specific route **'/a','/b','/c'.**.

Here is what I tried so far, but it does not work properly

```
const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password.length < 2) return;
    if (email.length < 2) return;

    try {
      const response = await apiClient.auth.login({
        username: email,
        password,
      });
      props.set_token(response.data.token);
      props.set_user_data(response.data.user);
      props.set_user_status({
        approved: response.data.user.approved,
        loggedIn: true,
        token: response.data.token,
      });
      if (response.status === 200) { //ON LOGIN SUCCESSFULL
        if (type.user.user_type === "A") {
          <Redirect to="/A" />;
        } else if (type.user.user_type === "B") {
          <Redirect to="/B" />;
        } else if (type.user.user_type === "C"){
          <Redirect to="/C" />;
        }
        else{
          <Redirect to="/signin" />;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is React Router to accomplish this... Resource to help you [React Router](https://flaviocopes.com/react-router-data-from-route/)

Try replacing your conditional block with this instead

```
if (response.status === 200) { //ON LOGIN SUCCESSFULL
    if (type.user.user_type) {
      <Redirect to={`/${type.user.user_type}`}/>;
    }  else {
      <Redirect to="/signin" />;
    }
```

Comment: I am using react router(Redirect)

Comment: What does your usertype returns??

Comment: It returns a string value of a usertype

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router v6, you need to use the useNavigate hook:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

And then:

```
if (type.user.user_type === "A") {
  navigate('/A');
} else if (type.user.user_type === "B") {
  navigate('/B');
} else if (type.user.user_type === "C"){
 navigate('/C');
}
```